# Setting up xorg with esperanto circumflexes

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, dvorak

I am trying to set up my keyboard to be a normal dvorak keyboard with the circumflexes from Esperanto added onto the keys where it makes sense to have them. This means ŝ as a modifier on the s key, ĉ as a modifier on the c, and so forth.

However, with a setup that appears to me to be correct, I instead just get no response when I press the relevant key combinations.

`X11/xkb/symbols/epo` lists partial keymappings, that apply the circumflexes based on whether the base keyboard is querty, dvorak, or colemak. For instance, here is a bit from the qwerty section:

```
partial
xkb_symbols "qwerty" {
    key <AB03> { [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, ccircumflex, Ccircumflex ] };
    key <AC05> { [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, gcircumflex, Gcircumflex ] };
    key <AC06> { [ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, hcircumflex, Hcircumflex ] };
```

When I look at `evdev.lst` or at `base.lst`, I find this section called `esperanto`, `esperanto:qwerty`, and `esperanto:dvorak` which I think should be apply one of the above sections, meaning that `AltGr-c` would generate a lowercase c with a circumflex.

The right-alt key on my keyboard generates scancode 108, which some places on the internet have said is traditionally `AltGr` or `ISO_Level3_Shift`. But xev is quite clear that this is `Alt_R`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x6c0, subw 0x0, time 28019153, (69,719), root:(1033,739),
    state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Finally, here is the xorg configuration that I am trying to set up. I will note that neither keyboard generates the modified characters, even though xev indicates that pressing right-alt and `c` generates `Alt_R` and `c`.

```
      Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "built-in keyboard"
        MatchProduct "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
        Option "XkbLayout" "dvorak"
        Option "XkbOptions" "esperanto:dvorak"
      EndSection

      Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "ErgoDox EZ"
        MatchVendor "ZSA"
        MatchProduct "ZSA Ergodox EZ"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us"
        Option "XkbOptions" "esperanto:qwerty"
      EndSection
```

As it stands, I don't know if the problem is that my keyboard doesn't generate the AltGr scan code, or that AltGr now means something completely different, or that my keyboard options are inccorrect. I would appreciate help in making this work, or at least understanding why it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, found it.

After a lot of research, I learned that I was actually rather close. The issue is that US keyboard layouts do not actually have level-3 enabled by default.

I stumbled upon [this page](https://stesie.github.io/2018/09/nixos-custom-keyboard-layout-revisited) where I saw `lv3:ralt_switch` clearly there in the `XkbOptions` section.

So, I have now revised my Xorg config sections to look like this:

```
      Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "built-in keyboard"
        MatchProduct "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us"
        Option "XkbVariant" "dvorak"
        Option "XkbOptions" "esperanto:dvorak,lv3:ralt_switch"
      EndSection

      Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "ErgoDox EZ"
        MatchVendor "ZSA"
        MatchProduct "ZSA Ergodox EZ"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us"
        Option "XkbOptions" "esperanto:qwerty,lv3:ralt_switch"
      EndSection
```

Note that both keyboards are set to the US layout, with the internal one set to the dvorak variant (because, again, the external one is an Ergodox and I've flashed a layout to the hardware). Adding `lv3:ralt_switch` enables AltGr on my right alt. With `esperanto:dvorak` and `esperanto:qwerty` in the relevent sections, I now have both keyboards working as I described in the beginning of my question.